# How do I hide players on a Google Play Leader board?

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard

I have a couple people who cheated and inputted a fake score on my Android games's leader board. I have tried Google's Hide-o-matic tool, but I can seem to get it to work. I input the various values, but it does not give me the option to sign in. I have also tried reading the documentation from google, but I have no idea how to use http requests. can someone point me in the right direction for how to solve this problem?

hide-o-matic tool:
https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools/tree/master/tools/hide-o-matic

documentation: 
https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide

Comment: It just plain doesn't do anything. When I refresh after changing the values, it still displays the same screen as before.